# Isolate the instantiation of an annotation

Tags: java, kotlin, annotations, openapi, javalin

I have a huge `@OpenApi` annotation (basically it's documentation of a [Javalin](https://javalin.io/)/Kotlin endpoint) which occupies a lot of lines:

```
@OpenApi(
   summary = "",
   description = "Lists all customers",
   path = "customers",
   queryParams =
   // ...........
   // ...........
   // etc
)
override fun handle(context: Context) {
   // body of the REST handler
}
```

I have to scroll a lot to see the actual handler.
Hence, I'd like to isolate it somehow like:

```
@GetCustomersDoc
override fun handle(context: Context) {
   // body of the REST handler
}
```

I'm OK with other solutions that make the documentation go elsewhere.

This would make the code cleaner and the docs segregated.

Comment: Does `OpenApi` support annotation composition?

Comment: HI! Just wanted to check if there was some problem with what I proposed and if I can clarify anything?

Comment: really sorry I'll check tomorrow at work. I just forgot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so what you want is the `@OpenApi` docs to be separated from the REST handler code. You can do that by moving away the implementation rather than moving away the annotation.

So in your current file with all the `@OpenApi` annotations mixed with REST handler code, you call helper functions, like this:

```
@OpenApi(
   summary = "",
   description = "Lists all customers",
   path = "customers",
   queryParams =
   // ...........
   // ...........
   // etc
)
override fun handle(context: Context) {
   handleGetCustomers(context)
}
```

and then you put - either in the top of that file or in another file for even more segregation - all REST handlers, which allows you to scroll among them without the noise of `@OpenApi` annotations:

```
// Collected at the top of the file, or in a separate file
fun handleGetCustomers(context: Context) {
    // body of the REST handler
}
```

Then you can easily scroll among your REST handler code without being bothered by `@OpenApi` noise.

Note that you should use the *Go To* -> *Definition* functionality of Android Studio to avoid having to scroll to `handleGetCustomers()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could define separate Annotations:

```
annotation class MyOwnApi(
    val openApi: OpenApi = OpenApi(
          summary = "",
          description = "Lists all customers",
          path = "customers",
          queryParams =
          // ...........
          // ...........
          // etc
        )
)

annotation class UserOpenApi(
        val openApi: OpenApi = OpenApi(
              summary = "Something",
              description = "Lists all users",
              // ...........
              // ...........
              // etc
            )
    )
```

Pros:

- Code separation
- Reusable annontation classes
- You could even make a builder class and test it

Cons:

- Confusing
- Annotations can't inherit, extend classes or implement Interfaces
- **May not be possible** to implement or require complex code changes, if the classes/objects are checked for `@OpenApi` directly. In this case, you would need another reflective search to pull the annotation from a field!

Comment: I think you commented the wrong post? Your post gives a good solution too, but the scrolling problem is still there, because you would need to scroll down to see the helping method

Comment: Misplaced comment deleted. No need to scroll btw, one just use the *Go To* -> *Definition* functionality of Android Studio.

Comment: how to use that new annotation?

Comment: @LuísSoares Annotate your class as usual `@MyOwnApi class Clazz { ... }`